# November 2011 Community Moderator Election RESULTS

Tags: discussion, moderators

Well, [it's finally over.](https://stackoverflow.com/election) Our year-end excuse for navel-gazing has come to an end, with four new moderators fresh from the turkey-fryer and ready to volunteer their formerly-precious free time in service to the users of Stack Overflow:

[image: boltclock] [image: NullUserException] [image: casperone] [image: anna-lear]

Let's take a moment to give a hearty meta-welcome to our new moderators, before they get turned loose on the site and destroy us all...

I also wish to announce that veteran moderators [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) and [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) are hanging up their mod-hats. Moderating a site the size of Stack Overflow can be a thankless job at times, so please join me now in thanking them both for their service, and wishing them all the best as they rejoin the esteemed ranks of Stack Exchange experts.

<sub><sup>*Now back to your regularly-scheduled Meta Madness...*</sup></sub>

Comment: *Congratulations* to all of our new moderators and a fresh round of *thanks* to our current diamonds!  You guys rule.  Keep up the good work!

Comment: FRESH FISH, FRESH FISH :)  Congratulations to all!

Comment: SLaks??? Oh no :( Well, thanks for everything you've done! And Gumbo too.

Comment: i imagine that so moderators get paid 10 times as much as forums.asp.net moderators ~~ thank you all for doing a thankless job. congratulations!  B-)

Comment: @gerryLowry Only if forums.asp.net moderators are also volunteers. ;)

Comment: @gerryLowry: Actually, guess who does the paying...?

Answer (score 36):

Yay!  And I'd like to say to our new mods...

## COFFEE BREAK IS OVER, BACK ON YOUR HEADS!

Answer (score 13):

**Congratulations, you four!**

*You few, you proud, you...moderators.*

Comment: we prefer the term "victims"

Comment: We few, we happy few, we band of... siblings.

Comment: @mmyers: Comrades? Colleagues? Suckers?

Comment: @Adam Robinson: peons

Comment: Well, *brothers* doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: @mmyers including AnnaLear?

Answer (score 6):

Excellent job, mods! Now stop slacking off, go back to SO and work!